# Volley - API call data Is not showing in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am creating a news app and in this app I am getting data of news by a API call from Volley Library To URL.

My app is starting but not showing anything in the view.

Here is the **MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.arne.khabriapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NewsItemClicked {

    private val mAdapter: NewsListAdapter by lazy{
        NewsListAdapter(this)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        fetchData()

        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        val url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=9bb7bf6152d147ad8ba14cd0e7452f2f"
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            {
                val newsJsonArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
                val newsArray = ArrayList<NewsClass>()
                for (i in 0 until newsJsonArray.length()){
                    val newsJsonObject = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val news =NewsClass(
                        newsJsonObject.getString("title"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("author"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("url"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                    )
                    newsArray.add(news)
                }
                mAdapter.updateNews(newsArray)
            },
            {
            }
        )
        MySingletonClass.getInstance(this).addRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    override fun OnItemClick(item: NewsClass) {
    }
}
```

Here is the **NewsAdapter.kt**

```
package com.arne.khabriapp

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

//class Name: extendItForRecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderClass>
class NewsListAdapter( private val listener: NewsItemClicked): RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsViewHolder>()
{

    private val items: ArrayList<NewsClass> = ArrayList()
//    call me when each time one viewholder is created
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsViewHolder {

    //Layout Inflater  - Converts XML into View
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.itemnews, parent, false)

    val viewHolder = NewsViewHolder(view)
    view.setOnClickListener{
        //this is a call back to main activity so the main activity knows that any item is clicked and then the mainn activity behave according to this.
        listener.OnItemClick(items[viewHolder.adapterPosition])
        
    }
        return viewHolder
    }

    //    I will bind the item with viewholder
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = items[position]
        holder.titleView.text = currentItem.title
    }

//    call me only one time i will give you how many item will be here in list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun updateNews(updatedNews: ArrayList<NewsClass>){
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(updatedNews)

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
class NewsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val titleView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
}

interface NewsItemClicked{
    fun OnItemClick(item: NewsClass)
}
```

Here is the **Logcat** Which is not showing any error but, I don't know why it is giving this error -

```
2021-01-21 09:46:43.437 20378-20378/? I/.arne.khabriap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-01-21 09:46:43.529 20378-20378/? E/.arne.khabriap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-01-21 09:46:43.533 20378-20378/? W/.arne.khabriap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-01-21 09:46:44.250 20378-20417/com.arne.khabriapp D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2021-01-21 09:46:44.250 20378-20417/com.arne.khabriapp W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2021-01-21 09:46:44.244 20378-20378/com.arne.khabriapp W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:118): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=8411 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c146,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
2021-01-21 09:46:44.481 20378-20417/com.arne.khabriapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-01-21 09:46:44.496 20378-20417/com.arne.khabriapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-01-21 09:46:44.510 20378-20417/com.arne.khabriapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-01-21 09:46:44.782 20378-20378/com.arne.khabriapp W/.arne.khabriap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-01-21 09:46:44.785 20378-20378/com.arne.khabriapp W/.arne.khabriap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-01-21 09:46:45.006 20378-20424/com.arne.khabriapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-01-21 09:46:45.134 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd59572d0, tid 20415
2021-01-21 09:46:45.148 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-01-21 09:46:45.197 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-01-21 09:46:45.240 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2021-01-21 09:46:45.240 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd591a420: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2021-01-21 09:46:45.250 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd591a420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd590f8a0)
2021-01-21 09:46:45.330 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-01-21 09:46:45.337 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-01-21 09:46:45.338 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd59575f0, tid 20415
2021-01-21 09:46:45.346 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-01-21 09:46:45.347 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2021-01-21 09:46:45.347 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
2021-01-21 09:46:45.427 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd591a420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd590f8a0)
2021-01-21 09:46:45.431 20378-20415/com.arne.khabriapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
```

Comment: recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter // init adpter here
fetchData() /then fetch data from network

Comment: @HasanMohdKhan Can you please share it in answer form.

Comment: ok I please see in answer.

Comment: Now this error occurring - 


2021-01-21 14:09:57.895 4475-4500/com.arne.khabriapp E/Volley: [11762] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=***********************************************


Please help

Comment: please check API doc for error code 403

Comment: @HasanMohdKhan No Description is given for error code 403 on API Docs